# Why do I get umask 022 as default in my main user instead of the 0002 one?

Tags: permissions, umask

I'm using `Fedora 34 (Workstation Edition)` —although I've seen this same behaviour on a `Debian Buster` machine, and I'm trying to understand why the users that I am creating are getting the umask `0002` by default, whereas my main user gets `0022` instead.

If I do `id` and `umask` with my main user, I get the following output:

```bsh
mikelalejobr@fedora:~$ id
uid=1000(mikelalejobr) gid=1000(mikelalejobr) groups=1000(mikelalejobr),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
mikelalejobr@fedora:~$ umask
0022
```

Now, I create a new user and I change its password:

```bsh
mikelalejobr@fedora:~$ sudo useradd myNewUserUmask
mikelalejobr@fedora:~$ sudo passwd myNewUserUmask
```

Finally I log in as the new user and issue an `umask` command:

```bsh
[myNewUserUmask@fedora mikelalejobr]$ cd
[myNewUserUmask@fedora ~]$ id
uid=1003(myNewUserUmask) gid=1003(myNewUserUmask) groups=1003(myNewUserUmask) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[myNewUserUmask@fedora ~]$ umask
0002
```

Checking `/etc/bashrc`, there's the following condition:

```bsh
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
       umask 002
    else
       umask 022
    fi
```

If I run the following script in my main account, I get:

```bsh
mikelalejobr@fedora:~$ if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then echo "Umask 002"; else echo "Umask 022"; fi
Umask 002
```

The same that in the freshly created account:

```bsh
[myNewUserUmask@fedora ~]$ if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then echo "Umask 002"; else echo "Umask 022"; fi
Umask 002
```

I haven't changed any files like `/etc/bashrc` nor `/etc/profile`, and I've tried logging in as the `newTestUserUmask` using the `GDM` to check if that could be "the issue", but with no luck.

So, what am I missing here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked `.bashrc` and other dotfiles in your home directory?

Comment: @JohanMyréen, it's nearly a fresh installation of Fedora. If I do a `grep 'umask' .bashrc` I get no results. In fact, I must say that I use `zsh`, but for this question I purposely used `bash` instead to try to understand what is going on.